# Cannot Open App From Google Play Store After Installing it

Tags: flutter, google-play-services, developer-console

After i Publish my App to Google Playstore i cant open it from google play, even test from another device, its same isuue.Its showing UNINSTALL Button Only ANY ONE Please help me what mainfest need to Add and what the things make this issue?i am so stressed up now

Neeed help to fix my Mainfest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed something in your **Manifest.xml**.

Check all **activity/permission's** in **Manifest.xml**

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="id.co.appname">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <application
        android:label="appname"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="6575675h567h567h57h5h7577h5"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true"> <!-- Set this attribute to true or false based on your app's requirements -->
            <!-- ... other attributes ... -->
            <!-- ... intent-filter ... -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity android:name="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:exported="false"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then check your firebase `google-services.json` and `SHA-1 Key`